# how to install a color scheme with yadr

Tags: vim, colors, gvim, macvim, vim-plugins

someone advised me to use [yadr](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles), which is supposed to make installing dotfiles etc much easier for vim

however I just couldn't figure out a way to install [base16](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim) through yadr..

before I had to simply do these two steps:
1. copy the color profile file into `~/.vim/colors`
then put this in my `.vimrc file: :colors %color name%`

but now that simply doesn't work.. it keeps on telling me it cannot file the color file.. but them i'm not sure where to put it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing your files in:

```
~/.vim/colors/
```

eg:

```
~/.vim/colors/base16-bright.vim
```

and doing:

```
:colorscheme base16-bright
```

or appending:

```
colorscheme base16-bright
```

to your `~/.vimrc` should work, even with that stupid distribution.

Yadr itself doesn't "make installing dotfiles etc much easier for vim" but the "vim" part of that stupid distribution uses Vundle, a popular plugin manager, for that so you should probably play ball andinstall base16 through Vundle by adding a line to [that file.](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vundles/appearance.vundle)

Or get rid of that crap and configure *your* environment *yourself*.

Comment: i did add a line to that file.. but i'm still getting that base16 doesn't exist as a color scheme.. is there like some vundle install command or something after i edit the appearance.vundle file?

Comment: ok i got it.. i just ran this `vim +BundleInstall +qall` and then i put `colorscheme base16-ocean` in `~/.vim/settings/yadr-appearance.vim` and it works fine now!

Comment: but why the strong emotion against yadr? i still didn't get that part

Comment: I am strongly opposed to using overarching pre-baked configs in general and for Vim in particular. It adds complexity where there is little or none, it prevents *you* from actually taking control of *your* environment for the sake of "productivity" and "speed", it prevents you from actually learning how to hack it by shielding you from having to go through the basics and so on.

Comment: well said @romani